# Is it possible to control page-out and page-in by user programming? If yes then how?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel

My questions are as follows:

I **mmap**(memory mapping) a file into the virtual memory space.
When I access the first byte of the file using a **pointer** at the first time, the OS will try to access the data in memory, but it will fails and raises the **page fault**, because the data doesn't present in memory now. So the OS will swap the data from disk into memory. Finally my access will success.

(question is coming)
**When I modify the data(in-memory) and write back into disk file, how could I just free the physical memory for other using, but remain virtual memory for fetching the data back into memory as needed?**
It sounds like the page-out and page-in behaviors where the OS know the memory is exhaust, it will swap the LRU(or something like that) memory page into disk(swap files) and free the physical memory for other process, and fetch the evicted data back into memory as needed. But this mechanism is controlled by OS.

For some reasons, I need to control the page-out and page-in behaviors by myself.  So how should I do? Hack the kernel?

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this? What is the actual problem you try to solve? What is the use-case?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am studying the "Anti-caching" approaches which proposed by H-Store team. "Anti-caching" is similar with VMM in OS. They both want to handle the situation that the data size is much larger than memory size. I want to implement a user-space VMM for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`madvise`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) system call. Its behaviour is affected by the `advice` argument; there are many choices for advice and the optimal one should be picked based on the specifics of your application.

The flag `MADV_DONTNEED` means that the given range of physical backing frames should be unconditionally freed (i.e. paged out). Also:

> After a successful `MADV_DONTNEED` operation, the semantics of
>     memory access in the specified region are changed: subsequent
>     accesses of pages in the range will succeed, but will result
>     in either repopulating the memory contents from the up-to-date
>     contents of the underlying mapped file (for shared file
>     mappings, shared anonymous mappings, and shmem-based
>     techniques such as System V shared memory segments) or zero-
>     fill-on-demand pages for anonymous private mappings.

This could be useful if you're absolutely certain that it will be **very** long until you access the same position again.

However it might not be necessary to force the kernel to actually page out; instead another possibility, if you're accessing the mapping sequentially is to use `madvise` with `MADV_SEQUENTIAL` to tell kernel that you'd access your memory mapping mostly sequentially:

> Expect page references in sequential order.  (Hence, pages in the given range can be aggressively read ahead, and may be freed soon after they are accessed.)

or `MADV_RANDOM`

> Expect page references in random order.  (Hence, read ahead may be less useful than normally.)

These are not as aggressive as explicitly calling `MADV_DONTNEED` to page out. (Of course you can combine these with `MADV_DONTNEED` as well)

---

In recent kernel versions there is also [the `MADV_FREE` flag](https://lwn.net/Articles/591214/) which will lazily free the page frames; they will stay mapped in if enough memory is available, but are reclaimed by the kernel if the memory pressure grows.

Comment: thanks. I have read some materials about the `madvise`. A new question is that after using the `madvise` system call, the new data content in physical memory range will be flushed back to the mapped file, then the physical backing frames will immediately be freed?

Comment: @Gemsnail there is no guarantee of *that*, AFAIK. But it is inconsequential. All in all the kernel is also caching block-device contents in its block-cache layer, and you wouldn't really be flushing that.

Comment: actually I use `mmap` to allocate a large memory with flags `MAP_ANONYMOUS`. After operating lots of memory data command(physical memory is nearly exhaust), if there is a new data coming, I will write the LRU data(in-memory, but mapped with a specific range of virtual memory) back to disk and call the `madvise` over that specific virtual memory range. Then I add the new data into memory, will the system use the `madvised` memory first for the new data, rather than incur OS swapping to give free memory space?

Comment: @Gemsnail if you said `MADV_DONTNEED` then the OS most probably would consider using these pages. However unless you lock the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` the OS can LRU-page-out this area as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can checout  mlock+munlock to lock/unlock the pages.  This will give you control over pages being swapped out.

You need to have CAP_IPC_LOCK capability to perform this operation though.